# Passing unknown as generic in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm using this [npm package](https://github.com/spring-media/aws-lambda-router) where, among other stuff, they use the following types (this is a simplified version of the types in that package):

```
export interface APIGatewayProxyStructuredResultV2 {
    statusCode?: number;
    headers?: {
        [header: string]: boolean | number | string;
    };
    body?: string;
    isBase64Encoded?: boolean;
    cookies?: string[];
}
export interface APIGatewayProxyEvent {
    version: string;
    routeKey: string;
    rawPath: string;
    body?: string;
}
type ProxyIntegrationBody<T = unknown> = {
    body?: T;
};
type APIGatewayEventRequestContext = {
    key: string;
}
export type ProxyIntegrationEvent<T = unknown> = Omit<APIGatewayProxyEvent, 'body'> & ProxyIntegrationBody<T>
export type ProxyIntegrationResult = Omit<APIGatewayProxyStructuredResultV2, 'statusCode'> & {
    statusCode?: APIGatewayProxyStructuredResultV2['statusCode'];
};
export interface ProxyIntegrationRoute {
    path: string
    method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'OPTIONS' | 'PUT';
    action: (
    request: ProxyIntegrationEvent<unknown>,
    context: APIGatewayEventRequestContext
    ) => ProxyIntegrationResult | Promise<ProxyIntegrationResult> | string | Promise<string>
}
export interface ProxyIntegrationConfig {
    routes: ProxyIntegrationRoute[];
}
```

Then in my code, I'm trying to use the types as follows

```
const handler: ProxyIntegrationConfig = {
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/playedGames',
            method: 'POST',
            action: async (request: ProxyIntegrationEvent, context) => {
                return { statusCode: 200, body: '' };
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/playedGames',
            method: 'POST',
            action: async (request: ProxyIntegrationEvent<{ name: string, numbers: string[] }>, context) => {
                return { statusCode: 200, body: '' };
            }
        },
    ]
};
```

If I understand generics correctly, I should be able to pass a custom type to `ProxyIntegrationEvent` via generics, however, I'm getting the following typescript error in the second object of the routes array:

```
Type '(request: ProxyIntegrationEvent<{ name: string; numbers: string[]; }>, context: APIGatewayEventRequestContext) => Promise<{ statusCode: number; body: string; }>' is not assignable to type '(request: ProxyIntegrationEvent<unknown>, context: APIGatewayEventRequestContext) => string | ProxyIntegrationResult | Promise<...> | Promise<...>'.
  Types of parameters 'request' and 'request' are incompatible.
    Type 'ProxyIntegrationEvent<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ProxyIntegrationEvent<{ name: string; numbers: string[]; }>'.
      Type 'ProxyIntegrationEvent<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ProxyIntegrationBody<{ name: string; numbers: string[]; }>'.
        Types of property 'body' are incompatible.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; numbers: string[]; } | undefined'.ts(2322)
Untitled-1(29, 5): The expected type comes from property 'action' which is declared here on type 'ProxyIntegrationRoute'
```

If I remove the generic and simply do `(request: ProxyIntegrationEvent, context)`, as I have in the first object of the routes array, it fixes the problem but that defeats the whole purpose because it doesn't give me any typing for the `request` parameter.

Am I using these types incorrectly or is this some typing bug in the package? I'm thinking of forking that project anyway so I could fix it if needed.

Comment: Please [edit] the code here to be a self-contained [mre] that doesn't rely on external, third-party, or private definitions to demonstrate your issue.  Ideally we could paste the code into our own IDEs and immediately get to work on the problem.  Right now there are [lots of errors](https://tsplay.dev/w8Vbpm) unrelated to your question that we'd need to wade through before we get something testable.

Comment: @jcalz updated. People should be able to repro after installing the `aws-lambda-router` package

Comment: Does that mean the question depends on aws-lambda? Then you might want to tag it as such, since we can't necessarily expect people to install packages.  You might want to acutally *remove* third-party dependencies from the example (a [mre] isn't necessarily supposed to be an excerpt of your actual code, but a self-contained example that displays the same issue as your actual code), since that will make it more accessible and thus more likely to receive a useful response.

Comment: @jcalz I added all the types that I'm using so it can repro without having to install any dependency

Comment: Okay so now I can repro it and... yeah you're *either* using the type incorrectly or the type is wrong.  If you're willing to change the types then maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1a1yw) is what you're looking for.  Does that work as expected? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Is it possible to fix `ProxyIntegrationEvent` without having to modify `ProxyIntegrationConfig`? I found that updating `request: ProxyIntegrationEvent<unknown>,` to `request: ProxyIntegrationEvent<any>,` fixes the problem and I still have typing in the request parameter, it just feels weird to use `any`

Comment: The question is really what you're trying to accomplish.  You say "you still have typing in the request parameter", but I'd like to see you *use* `handler` afterwards, since the type `ProxyIntegrationConfig` will completely forget about the types.  `any` will make the error go away (that's pretty much what `any` does) but if that's all you care about you could put `any` just about anywhere.  What, specifically, is the use case here?

Comment: I'd like `ProxyIntegrationEvent` to be able to take any custom type that I want or not type (I'm also ok passing `unknown` when no specific type is needed). For example, `request: ProxyIntegrationEvent<MyCustomType>` or `request: ProxyIntegrationEvent`. Basically, I need `ProxyIntegrationEvent` to be flexible to take different types of body parameters from different network requests.

Comment: I asked how you used `handler` but you haven't shown it.  Look at [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wRA95W); if I use my suggestion then the compiler knows what the `request` is for each element, but if I use your suggestion then it doesn't and allows incorrect things.  Does that truly not matter?

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Your solution actually prevents sending the wrong types, do you mind posting it so I can mark it as accepted? Thanks for bearing with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like `ProxyIntegrationConfig` to just *allow* the `request` callback param to be of a type narrower than `unknown`, then you can always just change `unknown` to `any` in various definitions like:

```
interface ProxyIntegrationRoute {
    path: string
    method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'OPTIONS' | 'PUT';
    action: (
        request: ProxyIntegrationEvent<any>, // edit
        context: APIGatewayEventRequestContext
    ) => ProxyIntegrationResult | Promise<ProxyIntegrationResult> | string | Promise<string>
}
```

But this loosens the type safety until things which are currently rejected for being unsafe are accepted *despite* being unsafe:

```
const handler: ProxyIntegrationConfig = {
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/playedGames',
            method: 'POST',
            action: async (request: ProxyIntegrationEvent, context) => {
                return { statusCode: 200, body: '' };
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/playedGames',
            method: 'POST',
            action: async (request: 
              ProxyIntegrationEvent<{ name: string, numbers: string[] }>, // okay
              context) => {
                return { statusCode: 200, body: '' };
            }
        },
    ]
};

declare const a: APIGatewayEventRequestContext
handler.routes[1].action(
    { rawPath: '', routeKey: "", version: "", body: { name: "a", numbers: [] } },
    a); // okay
handler.routes[1].action(
    { rawPath: '', routeKey: "", version: "", body: { oops: 123 } },
    a); // okay?
```

---

On the other hand if you want `ProxyIntegrationConfig` to both allow and *keep track* of these more specific types so that it can verify type safety, then it needs to be encoded into the type.

That means `ProxyIntegrationConfig` should maybe be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of the array of type arguments to the `ProxyIntegrationEvent<>` type for the `request` parameters in each element of the `routes` array.  Like this:

```
interface ProxyIntegrationConfig<T extends unknown[] = unknown[]> {
    routes: { [I in keyof T]: ProxyIntegrationRoute<T[I]> };
}
```

That's a [mapped array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), transforming the array/[tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of elements in `T` to a corresponding array/tuple of elements of `routes`.  That also means `ProxyIntegrationRoute` needs to be generic:

```
interface ProxyIntegrationRoute<T = unknown> {
    path: string
    method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'OPTIONS' | 'PUT';
    action: (
        request: ProxyIntegrationEvent<T>,
        context: APIGatewayEventRequestContext
    ) => ProxyIntegrationResult | Promise<ProxyIntegrationResult> | string | Promise<string>
}
```

So now we can give your `handler` an accurate type:

```
const handler: ProxyIntegrationConfig<[unknown, { name: string, numbers: string[] }]> = {
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/playedGames',
            method: 'POST',
            action: async (request, context) => {
                return { statusCode: 200, body: '' };
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/playedGames',
            method: 'POST',
            action: async (request, context) => {
                return { statusCode: 200, body: '' };
            }
        },
    ]
};
```

And note that this isn't really any harder to write, since you don't have to [annotate the `request` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) anymore.  And now we get the benefits of strong types:

```
handler.routes[1].action(
    { rawPath: '', routeKey: "", version: "", body: { name: "a", numbers: [] } },
    a); // okay

handler.routes[1].action(
    { rawPath: '', routeKey: "", version: "", body: { oops: 123 } }, // error!
    a);
```

---

Note that maybe `any` really is acceptable, since you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to avoid annotation of `handler` at all.  But all of that depends strongly on the use case for what you *do* with `handler`, which is probably ultimately out of scope here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.1.6#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAKQK4wC4FUZQCCIAnigN7ArUpQAecA9gE7YoCWI2UzAZkqkIAFAJIBxMNwDuYEkOaM6JAMrZmGRNgzMoAEwBKsDABtsANQBMFKjVs5JWAMKNdUAPwAuFCAwQARjwA3Da21AAWUGCuzDCe1qEJKADaEVE8XjjMnADmALpefoyMxpEgKAA+3r4BzBUomTnBiSgAvk2JhbokcQ0g2e0J7DAAQmAEAGwALACiIIguenGFxaUDofOMANbssD1qOUm5ay0htAwsbJzcfAIowuKSUDJyCkrTAG5QXPGJnzHsjBAGX2fTWtgUGG4AGkoCRgVlQadwWApEJJGF4Y0kTROt1MYjbCdbNgSHBUPJFCQRFwoNlmJIASBhi4SAAeAAqKAAvCgMCBNiBGFIQAA+bk-BK4uLs45rElku6iCTSWQfL7YQwARwwsGwzhpdDYPMozU2sPx-VORJo9CYrBQ8vJrypNLpDMBaq4HPFfIFQtF4oA8hB2NhWfdlU9ZBS3p8uAAaFAAclxSbFADIUDGXdw3dhGcyuhyRadbRcHaSnZTqbn6fnAYYYCYjShg6Hw0rHs9s6p1JptHpG83LImk-YtDBnK40yhMybEuOnAs4hGu9Hnb2NFodAYjKZLEkx9gHJOFkmjla1mX7VcePxkFnnTXaXXGfpGJDUPOEghsBj6iC2TYtQ0B-i4XhJmI0zskmdRJkIgbKDBcGBkI7IiIGAByyiwZU8G4DBYI0Eg9ZAigAAUwGhDo2q6l42bPnmjKemGYCkCKiYAPScbQuihlRtjzAa2BeKuKokCxWo6jg+rcIaVEAJTcmKDGuq+DZ7mwlQUiGBCsqptbuiAQ6mGKlS9NkdQ6UMUCshZJaEqW5w3jSNwPgZL5GfqvDsJZ37UR+3AwPRT5qUZ76focxzAKcQk4CgYRsboJTMCF1ZhaR3m+eK-ngoFsBeEkAk0LlzQ0L+-5JpxcDGLIegSNAMBJvGxUJKBYTgcmCFIc1rWhCRjJeGMJBzBRNHSSJj7pYZpEsYmQlydgSlcmKpVldRUDbmU5AASeU5QF4FgAAxHYmuIQbBbR9Y563UC0LW3RKj0oBVEHVbVJD1ZAsC9c9NDtZ18GITBD1-SgA2AkNMAjYgY1QLROBpUojHqSALGsjt4DQBaiY+P4PDBQBCLZIcrQcSgC30EtylPWDKA6FtFC7RO+2HSdZ0shdrREet1q86DCS5JeMW2K4iC1ToFOAvFYCiZ24mSfDE2yVTpyJSAyU8AAdBCQVJAAjLkWsQyAlHNDt9KouiF2JrrUAwnCKAAERO4mfwwINzuuyg51M1jB3O2A3t4zUhOky0rQC-1CmBCg3EoFsshq0lKU6-lMAG0bJtm4kFsomif42-T+UO14LtuwTnvlz7nNM0UcCE-rFgAMytJHVFgDHcc8Yn3QxScoDffAtwwlAcDsvSiCbIGvDspWMBPdelyufegjy1GLyUpu-Y7iZ5hWGtzNLq4cQh0EVGpNEsReIftgpJE0QWvkNcrGxdRn7U5mATz3NUVKFo-yGKMCYMw5gLF0EsIoJQ2I-w2NsXYFoopWicnaZe1xV6KgeOJbMLFaY0Hdp7CyP87alyJliZolsC7-iIX-FkexibRWJJWKayMMoFhZN6HkvpBTCjFMaWhXRpSylOI6TBkZniKwRnqQEi0cpUTNI7GhN0bTOTYKIjyTEPRxjDJyLh-IeEBh5G2MMYkN44O0aOVMGYWE5k8qRQsbJ2QORUagisCoNGoz3kGEMJj17dg3GoLcA5dxNn3BYUci5TzTmsYfSJ+0Vx+PXFvQJO9ByaQPEePaZ4LyEmCCg8st43JVlYTNN8+VOG8n0f6VaVFXpkL6FRAGugIJQWQnhbqbTkyoXQlhHCcEhAESTD-E2Xgc7rXGnRGxKMjLoycVHZolNDRyywRvSRysZGq2aMtFSoVSkaVCVpKaulbIePCppMy9TLLaQUMcuygFnF3XyS5dBtxTmZUBD5bI3oqZfF0Avbh-pSZ6L9MKQ4NSKHpxvskEQHAygKMYLwFA7Jn5vLKZ+DkSQRC5DFFdRysVpZsHVprVKUy2GAiyl8pIALhSJkxt9HGVR8YxEQbkVo2K5EQs-GHPqt9Eh1KqjVOqugGo-XmbdJpEEOm-TBiM8G0NRrkQmTgeaGzDTbLwX9Bm2htpHyiQHY6p0a5dC5risGfMyr3R5ddcq1tkzvSFSKpqYr1oSq6sDaVf1ZXDQVUq7AKrhLqt5eMza2qmZxIWGzQ1vskyXR-s0c18bnUoCFrk04YsJaoDimwWWYi1wSW0VJXUKt5K2CJanO2GdDbG00IyMZoQ85W0LsmZqxdPykOrgQyGXsObGr9vSwOwdqgE0KqyiOlrmid1jvHXuycNblvTpnatpE622AbVQouJDzTdpQJ2si1dfY7Xro3Fubd7rd1oMwBQzAACEHcu7ABaEAA)